# Putting a Django application into production on Ubuntu server with Apache2 and Cloudflare

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, django, cloudflare, mod-wsgi

I have this Django application which works very well, but I do not understand at all, how to put it in production on a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server using apache2 and to link it in HTTPS, on a domain such as shop.shopdeck.com
Here's the Django application in question:
https://github.com/Aftendo/shopdeck

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read up on Django deployment?

Comment: I'm new to Django, and asked on their discord, but otherwise tried this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Well, that's a ten year old tutorial. Have you read [the official documentation from the Django project?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/) I would suggest reading it, and asking concrete question on unclear topics. Open ended questions such as "How do I..." tend to be closed or receive no answers on this site - especially when the documentation upstream answers your question.

Comment: Ok, thank very much